# I cannot seem to specify which worksheet to perform a macro. Whatever I do, I get error 9

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets. "Sales" and "Marketing". I want to enact the macro on the sheet "Sales". I keep getting error 9 on line 4.

```vb
Sub halveandcolorchange()
    Dim Sa As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, A As Range, LastRow As Long
    
    Set Sa = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales")

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Sa.Range("B1:B" & LastRow)
    
    For Each cell In rng
        Set A = cell.Offset(0, -1)
        If cell.Value > 3 Then
           A.Value = A.Value / 2
           A.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: The obvious question, have you checked the sheet name 'Sales' is correct and don't have any leading/trailing spaces or other non-printing characters? Also, ss the sheet 'Sales' in the same workbook as the code?

Comment: LastRow doesnt reference Sa.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub halveandcolorchange()
    Dim Sa As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, A As Range, LastRow As Long
    Dim B As Double
    
    Set Sa = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales")

    LastRow = Sa.Cells(Sa.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Sa.Range("B1:B" & LastRow)
    
    For Each cell In rng
        Set A = cell.Offset(0, -1)
        If cell.Value > 3 Then
        B = cell.Value
           A.Value = B / 2
           A.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```